# I can not connect to the Win10 PC by ssh

Tags: windows-10, ssh

In my Macbook Pro I want to use ssh to connect my fellow's pc(Windows 10), but I can not connect it:

```
my_macbook_pro:~ ldl$ ssh 等拟@10.10.10.102
等拟@10.10.10.102's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I am quit sure the username and password is correct, but I can not connect success use ssh.

---

**EDIT**

The ssh is: FreeSSHd.  in Windows10 pc.

Comment: What kind of SSH service did you install?

Comment: @grawity do you mean the ssh on Win10?

Comment: try escaping the unicode, maybe? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171021/mount-command-can-not-contain-chinese-characters/171026#171026

Comment: @aircraft Yes. Did you install it manually, or was it pre-installed? What SSH server software did you use?

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried, but useless.

Comment: @grawity See my edit. I install the FreeSSHd in the Windows10 manually.